# Internet options ,IE11. delete download history

Tags: internet-explorer

Trying to find the path that IE keeps a downloadHisotry record. In Internet Options when deleting download history what is deleted and from which folder is deleted

Answer (score 0):

You could find the download history by opening Internet Explorer, selecting the **Tools**  button, and then select **View downloads**:
[image]

Here's [an article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17436/windows-internet-explorer-download-files-from-web) you could refer to. But if you have cleared the download list, I think there's no way to find the download history. You could also check [this link](https://kb.digital-detective.net/display/BF/Location+of+Internet+Explorer+11+Data) to find the paths of IE 11 data.